# How can I find current step label in Rundeck?

Tags: plugins, label, rundeck

How can I get the current step label from a custom Rundeck plugin in Java?

I am currently writing a custom step, and I need to find the step name and label:

```
import com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugins.step.NodeStepPlugin;

public class CustomNodeStep implements NodeStepPlugin {
    public void executeNodeStep(final PluginStepContext context,
                                   final Map<String, Object> configuration,
                                   final INodeEntry entry)
        throws NodeStepException {

        String executionId = context.getDataContextObject().get("job").get("execid");
        int step = context.getStepNumber();
        String stepLabel = ??
    }
}
```

[image: Custom Step Label Missing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, doesn't exist a way to get that value from a job via a plugin, the class doesn't contain that step information. Take a look at [this](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.rundeck/rundeck-core/1.6.0/com/dtolabs/rundeck/plugins/step/PluginStepContext.html).

You can suggest a class improvement [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).

Comment: I was able to extract these information from the description field in https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#getting-a-job-definition