# How to read other steps information from a custom step in Rundeck?

Tags: java, plugins, rundeck

Is there a way to access information about current job's steps from a custom step?
I would like to get the the name, type, read parameters of the upcoming steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by calling https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#getting-a-job-definition

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974367/10426011), that level of granularity isn't implemented yet. Right now you can obtain job-level info (take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0XKY.jpg)).